# Extract values from a specific column of an html table using bash

Tags: html, bash, awk, sed

I have an html table in which the first row is the title and the next rows represent the body of the table. I want to extract the values from the 3'rd column of each row. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below awk command,

```
awk 'NR>1{print $3}' file
```

This prints the value of third column except the one in the header.

Update:

```
awk -v RS='</tr>' -v F='<td>' '{$3=gsub(/<[^<>]*>/,"",$3);print $3}' file
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work. I think a delimiter (<td>) should be used in this case.

Comment: could you provide an example along with expected output?

Comment: awk -v RS='</tr>' -v F='<td>' '{print $3}' - this will print <td>value</td>. How can I extract the value from here?

Comment: `awk -v RS='</tr>' -v F='<td>' '{$3=gsub(/<[^<>]*>/,"",$3);print $3}' file`